# How to rename a cocoapod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a published Cocoapod, say it's named `abc-sdk`, I wish to fix its name (capitalization) to `Abc-SDK`. Is it possible?
I tried changing the `s.name` in the podspec (and the podspec file name capitalization as well) but when I run `pod trunk push` I get:

`[!] The following validation failed:
- Name is already taken.`

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hrm, so yes this can be changed (via a PR to the Specs repo), but it is not encouraged as it will break everyone's Podfile.

One other way to deal with this is to create a new Podspec outright and to use `deprecated_in_favor_of` on the older one to point to the new one. E.g. `AbcSDK` instead of `Abc-SDK`.

Comment: OK, went for the PR Specs repo technique and just capitalized pod name in the JSON file manually... let's see if they merge it. 
this looks worrying though:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/pull/12199

Comment: BTW anyone looking - Wayne's answer is the best one now :+1:

Comment: Searching github.com/CocoaPods/Core for “deprecated_in_favour_of” returns no results.  Searching for “deprecated_in_favor_of”, however, reveals implementations & usages throughout.  _Spelling!_  ||| Also, https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#deprecated_in_favor_of

Answer (score 8):

Create and push a new spec first, then deprecate the old spec in its entirety. CocoaPods now supports the following command (as of at least 1.0.0.beta.8):

```
pod trunk deprecate OLD_SPEC --in-favor-of=NEW_SPEC
```

https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-trunk/issues/31

Comment: Does not work in CocoaPods 1.2.1.  Spits out this error: `[!] An unexpected error occurred: <!DOCTYPE html><html> … <h2>Hello there, looks like you're lost.</h2><h3>Technically its a 404, but we're not too fussed.</h3> … </html>`.  _IMHO, the CocoaPods team should be a little more fussed when there's broken functionality lying about._

Comment: PRs are always welcome, there are only volunteers working on CP

Comment: This works. It shows a full 404 website on the terminal when you do it, but the deprecation is done correctly

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forking their repo instead? (the pre-`pod trunk` way).

Things to keep in mind:

- Once done, I'm sure there is a certain time window during which caches are still not purged.
- Changes might be breaking for users, running `pod install --no-repo-update`
- Changes might be breaking even for users updating the spec repo regularly, due to name mismatch – as you know by now, cocoapods are case sensitive.

Comment: is this method (forking specs repo) still supported?

Comment: also - is there a way to UNPUBLISH a pod and start fresh? (no users yet anyway)

Comment: sorry didn't get to answer in time, see @orta's answers